# Magento-Backend eav Module

Tags: magento, backend, entity-attribute-value

catalog_product_entity_int table we have one value column, can anyone help me to find the details that we are populating on the basis of which table.

as per my understanding that in the eav_attribute table, we can check the description regarding attribute but for the value of that attribute we can check in eav_attribute_option_value, I tried the same but for some default products some values i am not able to understand, kindly help me to understand the same.

like for 136 attributes, it coming 2
99 attribute it's coming 4

its new for me so please share any relevant link where i can get the eav module details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento uses [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). This way you can manage attributes without necessarily altering a table in order to add or remove attributes.

In Magento's architecture, the attributes are separated by it's type (datetime, decimal, int, text, varchar).

[image]

`eav_attribute` table contains all attributes created in every eav model in Magento. If you want to filter product's attributes, you can usually do a `SELECT * from eav_attribute where entity_type_id = 4`, where 4 is for `catalog_product` entity, mentioned at `eav_entity_type` table.

Once you filter that with the query above, you'll know what attributes are available for the *catalog_product* entity and in witch table they are.

[image]

This is how you can associate product attributes in Magento 1.x or 2.x.

The values of each attribute are saved in a relationship of entity_id and value.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ricardo for your comments. in your last image where you  highlighted int value like for 136 it 2 where I can check the mean of this 2, I am the new for the Magento

Comment: 136 is a tax class where the value is 2 so i am confused that its coming from where however there is no default value as well in the eav_attribute table for 136

Comment: That's a good question, @Yadav.
If you look back at `eav_attribute` table, you'll find a column `frontend_input`. When this value is `select` or `multiselect`, the column `source_model` must be filled with a PHP class containing it's options. For this particular attribute you'll see `Magento\Tax\Model\TaxClass\Source\Product`.
It's generally just a flat array, but this specific one is a bit more complex and will rely on the `tax_class` table, with some filters and rules applied (see the source class for details).

Comment: thank you very much for the details. is there any good website and blog where i can get such kind of details to understand, i tried to find some good content but i did not get it. thanks in advance for your help

Comment: No worries. I don't know a site that details this part very well. But I will make sure to publish some content related to this topic in my blog (magenteiro.com/blog). But it's in Portuguese. :)